# Trying to get CKEDITOR Simple Plugin (Part 1) Example to Work

Tags: ckeditor

I added the files provided in the zip download for the [Simple Plugin (Part 1) example](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1) to a web site with a working CKEDITOR setup. I made no changes to any of the files. A plugin called `abbr` is supposed to be defined by this code. After reloading the page containing CKEDITOR, I did not see the icon for the plugin appear after I added the plugin to `extraPlugins`. I then added a reference to the plugin in the `insert` toolbar but that also did not work.

I can get the plugin dialog to appear by binding to a keystroke, so at least that much works:

```
config.keystrokes = [
  [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 32 /*space*/, 'abbr' ]
];
```

Here is my `ckeditor.js`, after removing the Play Framework view markup (hopefully I did not miss any):

```
<script>
  function createEditor() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.BLAH;
    if (editor) {
      try { editor.destroy(true) ; } catch ( e ) { }
    }
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace("BLAH", {
      height: $(window).height() / 2 - 30,
      "extraPlugins": "imagebrowser,abbr,codemirror",
      on: {
        instanceReady: function(evt) {
          var maximized = $.cookie("maximized");
          var me = maximized=="true";
          if (me)
            editor.execCommand('maximize');
        },
        save: function(evt) {
          var scaytEnabled = CKEDITOR.plugins.scayt.state[evt.editor.name];
          $.cookie("scayt_enabled", scaytEnabled.toString(), { path: '/' });

          var maximized = evt.editor.commands.maximize.state==1;
          $.cookie("maximized", maximized.toString(), { path: '/' });
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is the JavaScript that launches CKEDITOR. `abbr` is the last plugin mentioned in `insert` toolbar:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.allowedContent = true;

  config.tabSpaces = 2;
  config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div';
  config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;

  config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'tools',       items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] },
    { name: 'document',    items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps',/*'Preview',*/'Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    //{ name: 'forms',       items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items : [ 'Image',/*'Flash',*/'Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe', 'abbr' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'styles',      items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'paragraph',   items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'/*,'-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'*/ ] },
    { name: 'links',       items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker','Scayt' ] }
  ];
};
```

I noticed that the instructions had a difference from the code; this code was shown in the instructions:

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'Abbr', {
    label: 'Insert Abbreviation',
    command: 'abbrDialog',
    toolbar: 'insert'
});
```

But the code in the download has a different value for `command`: `abbr`. Neither value worked. I tried adding `abbrDialog` to the `insert` section of `config.toolbar` but that did not work either. Perhaps there is still another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small bug in this tutorial - in the code you can download the command is named `abbr` when in the code samples it is `abbrDialog`.

But name of the button is all the time the same - `Abbr` (it's case sensitive!). So basically, your `config.toolbar` setting is incorrect, because you used lower cased name.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I wish the tutorial explained why things should be done instead of simply 'do this, this and this'.

Comment: What do you miss in this specific tutorial? I read it briefly and for me it seemed to contain a lot of information also about "why" (or "what does it mean"). But of course I'm rather biased :D

Comment: The list would be long. I suggest you run a usability study on the tutorials and the documentation. Another way to gather this type of information is to allow comments on the articles and documentation, then update the articles according to questions and comments that readers provide.

Comment: We did couple of usability studies, but we are not able to do them on entire documentation. That's why I'm asking :). As for comments/feedback - this is an interesting idea. At least we could make sending feedback easier, but moderated comments may be even more useful.

Comment: Here is an example of what I would find helpful: My plugin does not show any color; this is a problem because I styled Options to indicate status using inline styles (for example, <option style="color:#999">blah</option>). After reading http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_styles I am confused and I do not know what the author meant. There are no code examples, so unless the reader knows as much as the author they just scratch their head. It seems this information only applies to stylesheets, so I continue to search for reasons why the inline styles are ignored.

Comment: Here is another thing. I can insert HTML text if there is an enclosing span, but the cursor is left inside the span. How can I move the cursor just outside the span to I can insert a space between the inserted HTML and the previous contents of the line? If I press the space bar, &nbsp; is generated inside the span. If I call editor.insertText(" ") after inserting the span I get &nbsp; again. The docs don't seem to be set up to help.  I would prefer not to employ an enclosing span tag, btw, but again there is no 'philosophy of how to write a plugin', just a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks for comments. To be honest I don't understand the specific problem you had with styles, but I can see that the guide you linked is rather... vague. But the second part is a problem of different nature. It requires a certain knowledge about selection, ranges, DOM and CKEditor API built on top of them to implement features for editor. We can't document all of this, because these are huge topics (each for a book :D). We are focused on documenting our API and we plan to launch cookbook some day, so there are code snippets for most popular problems.

Comment: What I mean is that you can't expect to solve quickly every problem after just few days/weeks of working with a totally new technology. I can't myself solve some issues after few years - that's how complex things are when you deal with contenteditable, selection, focus and dozens of other topics that editing involves.

Comment: CKEDITOR is not totally new to me. I've been working with JavaScript, JQuery, CoffeeScript, Angular and other client-side programming environments for 18 years. In that time I have seen many things. I know the DOM, selectors, etc. I've been doing server-side programming much longer than that. The problem is that CKEditor API needs more and better documentation. Yes, it should be a goal that a competent programmer should be able to start writing good plugins quickly. Consider the similar case of writing Eclipse plugins.

Comment: When I started working with CKEditor I had years of experience in JS, jQ, DOM, etc., etc. But I knew nothing about selection and ranges and far less than I thought about... DOM. These are things that either you know because you worked with contenteditable before, or you know little / nothing about them. And in this case you must learn about them first if you want to be able to use CKEditor consciously and precisely. Of course in a perfect world this would be taught from the CKEditor book, but it is not yet this size of a project (...)

Comment: (...) and there are simply no resources to create such documentation. On the other hand, CKEditor's documentation is still far from the level that I would expect it to be - the decent level. We lack "something" in every field - precision, samples, general descriptions of concepts, etc. Also SEO is bad and that's in fact the biggest problem now. Currently we are working on a completely new set of samples which will precisely describe features and their options. But that's mostly for people integrating CKEditor with their pages. Besides that we are completing the API documentation (...)

Comment: (...) and e.g. based on your feedback we improved [some](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs/commit/d7c74d9245717b033f0eaf73bfe6024d4327aa7c) [guides](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs/commit/e70e4f3d500eb508bf420df5e8341bf67932f791). So it's getting better and better - especially in last two years. And CKEditor does not look bad in comparison with other similar projects (similar of size and complexity and being open source and size of active community). BTW. Don't forget it's open source and [documentation](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs) is on GitHub ;).

Comment: Good work, thanks for being so responsive. You can see my new plugin in action here: http://www.scalacourses.com/student/showLecture/153

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61014/discussion-between-mike-slinn-and-reinmar).